# Class and member documentation for Python 3.4 enumerations

Tags: python, enums

The enum support from standard Python 3.4 has been backported to Python 3.x and 2.x via the enum34 package in pypi.

Using the enum34 package in Python 2.7, I am quite disappointed to see how it behaves in the help() function of interactive python:

For example:

colors.py:

```
from enum import Enum
class Colors(Enum):
    """Enumeration of the three base colors"""
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

In python:

```
>>> import colors
>>> help(colors)
Help on module colors:

NAME
    colors

FILE
    <mypath>/colors.py

CLASSES
    enum.Enum(__builtin__.object)
        Colors

    Colors = <enum 'Colors'>
```

It does not even list the class description. :-(

1. How can the class description be shown in help() or pydoc?
2. How can the enum members be documented so that that documentation shows up in help() or pydoc?

Andy

Comment: You might consider reporting this as a bug or a feature request to the `enum34` maintainer.

Comment: It seems `pydoc.TextDoc().docclass()` can't handle these enumerations because it can't determined where some of their attributes are inherited from (so it falls back on a default description). Seems to be fixed in 3.4, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, `help()` (which is `pydoc`) is unable to properly display information on `Enum`s.  We had to do some fixing in 3.4 and later to get better results.

You can either display the `__doc__`s directly, or perhaps make your own `help()` wrapper that first checks if the object is an `Enum`, in which case you print the bits you want to know about, otherwise (or additionally) call the regular `help`.